# No HTTP run button (cant run on browser) : Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022

I'm novice in terms of using Microsoft Visual Studio Community edition. When I first created my webapi app (yesterday) in the run button (pointed at the pic), it says that I can run the http. But, today when Im planning to continue exploring it, there is no http(s) as one of the selection. Now my concern is how to make it appear again? I can build the app, but I cant run it into the browser.

Feel free to humiliate me :D haha.
Thank you for those who will response!

[image]

Comment: Make sure that your project have `launchSettings.json` with correct profiles as in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERKe4.png)

Comment: Have you loaded the sln file as solution? There's also an option to load a project "folder" which could cause problems starting your project :)

Comment: You may need to show more information to judge the specific reasons. For example, display the right file. It looks like you have entered the wrong file. Try to re -create an ASP.NET CORE Web MVC project, can it start HTTP correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay. Thanks for those who comments. It did trigger an idea to compare the new created project with the old one :D with some ticking I made it work. Thank you.

1. How did I open the project file, by clicking rigth+click:

[image]

2. Click the switch

[image]

3. Click the solution file .sln

[image]

4. Working!

[image]

Comment: Hi Tsokoloy, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)